# vector clear() does not seem to free memory allocated in push_back

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

Here is a simple program I tried out to understand memory alloc/free behavior with vectors. A struct has a `vector<int>` as its member. My understanding was a call to `clear()` of the vector will result in free of the memory of the vector element. But valgrind flags a memory leak.

The code looked simple enough but coming here after spending quite some time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct a {
    vector<int> v;
};

int main (void) {

    struct a *aptr = (struct a*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct a));

    aptr->v.push_back(10);

    aptr->v.clear();

    free(aptr);

    return 0;
}
```

```
==27649== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==27649==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27649==    by 0x4013A7: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:92)
==27649==    by 0x4011BE: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /homes/dineshb/code_tryout/c++/vectors/a.out)
==27649==    by 0x400DC8: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux<int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int&&) (vector.tcc:327)
==27649==    by 0x400BE3: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::emplace_back<int>(int&&) (vector.tcc:102)
==27649==    by 0x400B1D: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int&&) (stl_vector.h:840)
==27649==    by 0x400A68: main (vector.cpp:14)
==27649== 
==27649== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27649==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==27649==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27649==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27649==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27649==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Appreciate your guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Useful rule of thumb: don't mix C and C++.

Comment: Is there a special reason, why you wrap the vector into a struct?

Comment: e@MIkeMB I happened to see a similar piece of code and tried to understand the behavior.. no special reason.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `calloc` to instantiate an `std::vector`. That only reserves memory, but `std::vector` needs its constructor be called at some point. Similarly, you can't destroy a vector with `free`. Its destructor needs to be called.

You can fix your code like this:

```
int main () 
{
    a a_not_ptr;
    a_not_ptr.v.push_back(10);
}
```

This way, both the constructor and destructor are called. `std::vector`'s destructor takes care of clearing up its resources, so there's no need to call `a_not_ptr.v.clear()`

Comment: Maybe you could add a solution that creates the struct on the heap.

Comment: @MikeMB Hmm, probably not a great idea. OP might go and do that. Plus, it is easy enough to search for that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you.. makes a lot of sense now.